# git: post-update hook not firing

Tags: git

I'm trying to get a hook to execute on a server when a "git push" is run on my local computer. I am able to push code from my local computer and when I run "git pull" from the command line on the server, the changes will properly pull.

Here's what the hooks directory looks like:

```
sbirds@[xxx].com [~/public_html/app]# ls -l .git/hooks/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 sbirds sbirds 2048 Mar 31 18:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 sbirds sbirds 2048 Mar 31 18:33 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds  452 Mar 30 00:24 applypatch-msg.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds  896 Mar 30 00:24 commit-msg.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds  160 Mar 30 00:24 post-commit.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds  552 Mar 30 00:24 post-receive.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds   45 Mar 31 18:31 post-update*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds  189 Mar 30 00:24 post-update.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds  398 Mar 30 00:24 pre-applypatch.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds 1578 Mar 30 00:24 pre-commit.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds 4951 Mar 30 00:24 pre-rebase.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds 1239 Mar 30 00:24 prepare-commit-msg.sample*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbirds sbirds 3611 Mar 30 00:24 update.sample*
```

For now, I'm just running a simple script that makes a new directory. When I execute this script manually from the command line as "sbirds" user, it successfully makes the directory. Here's what the script looks like:

```
sbirds@[xxx].com [~/public_html/app]# cat .git/hooks/post-update
#!/bin/sh
mkdir $HOME/public_html/app/hook_folder
```

The config file:

```
sbirds@[xxx].com [~/public_html/app]# cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = sbirds@[xxx].com:/home/sbirds/repositories/app.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The OS info:

```
sbirds@[xxx].com [~/public_html/app]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-028stab070.5 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Fri Sep 17 15:37:23 MSD 2010
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be really appreciated.

Comment: You've left out the specifics of what you're actually doing - but from what you say, it sounds like you might be expecting the `post-update` hook on the *local* (pushed-from) repository to be executed? It's executed in the *remote* (pushed-to) repository.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to have code on the server update whenever I (or any of the other people committing) push new code. The hook I included obviously doesn't accomplish that, but since the issue seems to be with the hook actually executing, I thought I'd keep it simple. To accomplish this, I'd like for the hook on the server to execute when a push on my local computer is made.

Comment: Okay, just checking. Also, the easiest way to determine whether a hook is being run is to simply echo something. The output on the remote will be sent back to the terminal you're pushing from, and show up prefixed with `"remote: "`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I updated the `post-update` hook on the server to echo, but don't see any output on my local terminal. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: What are the `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment value on the server? See http://serverfault.com/questions/107608/git-post-receive-hook-with-git-pull-failed-to-find-a-valid-git-directory

Comment: If you can't see anything when you add an `echo hello` before the `mkdir`, then are you sure that you're pushing a new commit to the branch at all?  The hook won't be run if there's no update to be done - try adding a new commit locally and pushing again...  (This is a slightly annoying aspect to getting hooks to work.)